# Update MySQL table using pyspark

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, mysql-python, apache-spark-sql

I know it is not possible to just update a MySQL table using Spark, but I tried something to avoid it and it doesn't work.

Let's say I have a table `last_modification` where I save the user name as the id an the date of last modification from a system with different services. Each time I process some data I must update the date the data from that user was modified, and if a new user enters the system I must insert it to the table.

The process is:

1. Read the data from the SQL table:

   ```
   df_last_mod = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url=url, table="last_modification", properties=properties)
   ```
2. Extract from that DataFrame the users that will be processed (`last_mod_actual`) and keep the rest in an RDD (`last_mod_aux`):

   ```
   last_mod_actual = (df_last_mod
                  .rdd
                  .filter(lambda x: x[0] == service)
                  )
   ```
3. Update the modification date from the RDD of the processed users (now named `last_mod_rdd`), and join it to the RDD of the users that were not modified:

   ```
   union_rdd = last_mod_rdd.union(last_mod_aux)
   ```
4. This part it is an extra to avoid losing the data, but don't know if it could be ignored. Here I create a temporary table and cache it:

   ```
   header = (sqlContext
              .createDataFrame(union_rdd,header_schema)
              .createOrReplaceTempView("union_header")
              )
   sqlContext.cacheTable("union_header")
   ```
5. Finally I write the table using JDBC:

   ```
   dd = sqlContext.table("union_header")`

   dd.write.format('jdbc').options(
          url= url,
          driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
          dbtable="last_modification",
          user=user,
          password=password).mode('overwrite').save()
   ```

This code seems to work some times, but others only saves the modified users and erase the non-modified users. When inserting `dd.show()` before writing to the SQL table the program seems to work better, but don't know really why, it works a bit randomly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark SQL and MySQL- SaveMode.Overwrite not inserting modified data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41873495/spark-sql-and-mysql-savemode-overwrite-not-inserting-modified-data)

Comment: Please read my question carefully, is not the same question. In my code I'm creating an intermediate table in order to save the RDD and avoid the problem from the question you mention.

Comment: You don't create "intermediate table". You create __a view__ and caching in Spark is an optimization, not guarantee. What you do doesn't avoid the problem.

Comment: Is it a solution to guarantee that the view of the table is cached, or at least that the content of the DataFrame is not erased even if the original MySQL table is overwritten?

Comment: No, `cache` cannot be used for correctness in Spark. If you want to make it work, create a  __table__ (either in Spark or temporary one in MySQL).

Comment: With "create a table in Spark" you mean doing `registerTempTable`instead of `createOrReplaceTempView` ?

Comment: I mean `df.write.format(...).save(...)` or `df.write.format(...).saveAsTable(...)`.