# PySpark SQL overwriting returns empty table

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm migrating some data within a table, I am trying to change the value of the 'date' column, but it seems like PySpark erases the data while it is reading it.

I am doing the following steps:

- read data from a table
- change the value of a column
- overwrite the data to the same table

When I check the data after these steps, my table is empty.

Here is my code

```
table = "MY_TABLE" 

data_input = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url=JDBCURL, dbtable=table).load()
print("data_input.count()=", data_input.count())
print("'2019' in data_input:", data_input.where(col("date").contains("2019")).count())
print("'YEAR' in data_input:", data_input.where(col("date").contains("YEAR")).count())
# data_input.count()= 1000
# '2019' in data_input: 1000
# 'YEAR' in data_input: 0

data_output = data_input.withColumn("date", F.regexp_replace("date", "2019", "YEAR"))
print("data_output.count()=", data_output.count())
print("'2019' in data_output:", data_output.where(col("date").contains("2019")).count())
print("'YEAR' in data_output:", data_output.where(col("date").contains("YEAR")).count())
# data_output.count()= 1000
# '2019' in data_output: 1000
# 'YEAR' in data_output: 0
```

So far so good, let's overwrite the table

```
df_writer = DataFrameWriter(data_output)
df_writer.jdbc(url = JDBCURL, table=table, mode="overwrite")

# Let's check the data now
print("data_input.count()=", data_input.count())
print("'2019' in data_input:", data_input.where(col("date").contains("2019")).count())
print("'YEAR' in data_input:", data_input.where(col("date").contains("YEAR")).count())
# data_input.count()= 0
# '2019' in data_input: 0
# 'YEAR' in data_input: 0
# huh, weird

print("data_output.count()=", data_output.count())
print("'2019' in data_output:", data_output.where(col("date").contains("2019")).count())
print("'YEAR' in data_output:", data_output.where(col("date").contains("YEAR")).count())
# data_output.count()= 0
# '2019' in data_output: 0
# 'YEAR' in data_output: 0
# Still weird
```

And querying `SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE` returns 0 rows.

Why does [Py]Spark do this? How can I change this behaviour? Caching? Where is this explained in the docs?

Comment: Just for test, change ```df_writer``` line to ```data_output.write.jdbc(url = JDBCURL, table=table, mode="overwrite")```

Comment: Same thing, no data in the table after over writing

Comment: And after write, maybe execute again ```sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url=JDBCURL, db table=table).load()``` to update pyspark table metadata

Comment: Yup, did that too to refresh my data, got no data.

Comment: The JDBC user has permission to write data?

Comment: @Kafels: Yes, it has the permissions

Comment: Another approach is writing the data in another table, when Spark start to write the data in overwrite mode, it first clean up everything and after start write. And how you said, you are reading and saving in the same table, so how spark can save a data if everything was deleted?

Comment: Yeah, but I was thinking that Spark was a little bit more "intelligent" and noticed when it was over-writing the data it is reading. Seems like a big "gotcha".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41873495/spark-sql-and-mysql-savemode-overwrite-not-inserting-modified-data) explains why this goes wrong, I just had the same problem and adding `.cache()` after reading in the table fixed it for me, as is explained over there:

```
data_input = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url=JDBCURL, dbtable=table).cache()

data_output = [ do something with data_input ]

data_output.write.jdbc(url = JDBCURL, table=table, mode="overwrite")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around, by "caching" the dataframe:

```
data_pandas = data_output.toPandas()
data_spark = spark.createDataFrame(data_pandas)
data_spark.write.jdbc(url=JDBCURL, table=table, mode="overwrite")
```